# expo 48.09.9 and react-native 7.20.0 and i18n-js -

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have create a empty expo.dev project with latest version, and I follow this tutorial for use i18n-js library.

[this page](https://blog.logrocket.com/internationalization-and-localization-in-react-native/)

When I compile and run this error is generate

"TypeError: Cannot set property 'fallbacks' of undefined, js engine: hermes"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue when I accidentally upgraded from version 3.x.x to 4.x.x. They introduced breaking changes (as they should in a major version upgrade). Make sure you are using the correct version for your implementation.